# Holding the ball up with two hands

Tags: rules, basketball

I will like to know if it is a foul to take the ball from a player who picks the ball from a rebound and holds it up with two hands? Can the ball be taken from his hands even if they are held high up with both hands?

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE! Are you talking about the NBA? FIBA? There may be different rules for different leagues.

Answer (score 2):

There is no foul if a defender takes away the ball from a player (who had picked the ball from a rebound and held it with two hands - high or low) without contact. In addition, there may be contact allowed in accordance to **Rule 12B Section I (b)** below.

---

From the [2012-2013 NBA Rulebook](http://www.nba.com/.element/mp3/2.0/sect/podcastmp3/NBA/PDF/2012-13_NBA_Rule_Book.pdf). **Rule 12B Section I (b)** states:

> Contact initiated by the defensive player guarding a player with the
>   ball is not legal. This contact includes, but is not limited to,
>   forearm, hands, or body check.

There are several exceptions. Here is one relevant to your question:

> (5) Incidental contact with the hand against an offensive player shall
>   be ignored if it does not affect the player's speed, quickness,
>   balance and/or rhythm.
>
> > e. Contact which occurs on the hand of the offensive player, while that hand is in contact with the ball, is legal.